# MySql.Data.MySqlClient shows confusing error

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, visual-studio-2019, mysql.data

I'm using VS2019 and today I opened my project to continue working but a strange error occured that I really don't understand. The MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace shows this:

[image: mysql namespace]

and every mysql commands shows this error:

[image: error list]

but when I start the debugging it's working fine i don't know whats causing this since I'm not very knowledgeable with programming. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Try right click on solution then click Clean Solution. After cleaning right click again and click Rebuild Solution

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b it worked after refreshing the project thank you so much!! May I know what caused this error?

Comment: It seems that the reference to the MySQL library was not being read properly. It would be a bug in VS but such transient issues are hard to track down and probably not worth the effort if they can't be reproduced. Suffice it to say that it probably wasn't anything you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your scenario it's bit unclear what exactly problem at your end. You could try couple of hacks though

1. Clean solution and rebuild your project

If that does not resolve your issue, try to remove dll reference "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" from reference and referring to latest documentation from Microsoft, import correct namespace again. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I also thought of removing dll reference but I was afraid it would cause bigger errors. Cleaning, rebuilding and then refreshing the project worked tho. Thanks!